# Best way to calculate NDVI using 2 images

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, satellite-image

I have two sets of satellites images. One is a set of classical satellites images, and the other is a set of infrared satellites images. I am trying to detect the vegetation inside the yellow polygon and outside the red area using [Normalized difference vegetation index
(NDVI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalized_difference_vegetation_index).

1. Visible image

---

[image]

2. Infrared image

---

[image]

According to the image documentation, a shift in the color spectrum was made on the Infrared images: infrared band occupies the red band, red band occupies the green band...

To calculate the NDVI image, I'm doing the following :

```
# Images are in BGR color space.    
ndvi = (img_irc[:,:,2].astype(int) - img_visible[:,:,2].astype(int))/(img_irc[:,:,2] + img_visible[:,:,2] + 0.001)
```

Then, I use an Otsu threshold to extract the following mask :
[image]

To better see the effects, I add the semi-transparent mask of the impact of the detection on the satellite photo :
[image]

The result is not too bad, but there are sometimes wrong detections, like here on the roofs. I suspect that my way of extracting the spectral reflectance measurements acquired in the red (visible) and near-infrared regions by selecting the red channels is not perfect. Are there better methods to do so?

Comment: untouched source data please. no overlays. no false color/matplotlib screenshots.

Comment: As @ChristophRackwitz says, pure unadulterated images please, without axes, annotations or colour maps. Likewise please give all information you have about the wavelengths/filtration used in each. Thank youl

Comment: Sure, thanks. I've just modified my post.

Comment: okay... shadows are an issue, and the NIR channel seems faded out. the simple (NIR-red)/(NIR+red) formula doesn't cut it. something has to happen to these channels. a working example is needed... https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/17538947.2018.1495770

Answer (score 0):

The NIR channel has apparently already been preprocessed, by the translation of the spectrum. You should get closer to the source to get the values directly from the IR spectrum values, rather than re-creating the images.